Changing two levels at once in R
I have a table similar in structure to this:
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = factor(c("male", "mael", "female", "maale")),
  var2 = factor(c("sin", "dy", "dx", "sin")))

I want to rename the levels to correct the typos.
As var2 has only one option incorrectly, I can correct it with the simple
levels(df$var2)[levels(df$var2) == "dy"] <- "dx"
The var1 has two incorrectly written levels. And because I do not want to write each typo as its own line of code, I tried to correct it all at once using
levels(df$var1)[levels(df$var1) == c("maale", "mael")] <- "male"
However, this code does nothing. I think it will be the combination of == and c(), but I do not know how to fix it.
Does anyone know how to correct multile levels in just one line like this using base R without packages like dplyr and such? Thanks.

Use %in% not == for example levels(df$var1)[levels(df$var1) %in% c("maale", "mael")] <- "male"
